# the number does not return to the last id on the dynamic tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jquery to add and delete tabs dynamically.
but when I delete a tab, the ID does not return to the last number. but it actually increases and what appears is the last ID added.

this should start from 3 and not from 6
[image]

and when I delete and add new tab, why start from 11? this should be still start from 3 and till 7.

[image]

```js
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$(this).hasClass('add-pasal')) {
   $(this).tab('show');
  }
 })
 .on("click", "span", function () {
  var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
  $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
  $(this).parent().remove();
  $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
 });

 $('.add-pasal').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; 
        var tabId = 'pasal_' + id;
        $(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#pasal_' + id + '">Pasal '+ id +' <span class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span> </a></li>');
        $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '"><div class="panel-body"><textarea name="pasal" class="summernote"><h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h3></textarea></div></div>');

       $("#" + tabId + " .summernote").summernote();

        $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="tabs-container">

<div class="tabs-left">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#pasal_1">Pasal 1 </a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pasal_2">Pasal 2 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="add-pasal">+ Add Pasal</a></li>
 </ul>


 <div class="tab-content ">

  <div id="pasal_1" class="tab-pane active">
   <div class="panel-body">
    <textarea name="pasal" class="summernote">
     
     <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h3>
     dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <strong>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</strong> standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
     when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
     typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <ul>
      <li>Remaining essentially unchanged</li>
      <li>Make a type specimen book</li>
      <li>Unknown printer</li>
     </ul>
    </textarea>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pasal_2" class="tab-pane">
   <div class="panel-body">
    <textarea name="pasal" class="summernote">
     
     <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h3>
     dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <strong>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</strong> standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
     when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
     typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <ul>
      <li>Remaining essentially unchanged</li>
      <li>Make a type specimen book</li>
      <li>Unknown printer</li>
     </ul>
    </textarea>
   </div>
  </div>


 </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey that's because you are removing the `a` tag and not the `li` tag then you should edit this like let your code as is it and just edit this :

```
.on("click", "span", function () {
        var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
        $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();//add another parent here to fix that
        $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
    });
```

Comment: why when i delete the tabs, the number will return same value when i add again?

Comment: @AdityaDS Because you don't delete the `li` then the number of children of `.nav-tabs` has not decremented, then you should delete those `LI` tags or do as i suggest...

Comment: I have tried the code that you gave and the results as I just asked, why when I delete a tab, the number returns the same value when I add it again?

Comment: @AdityaDS you can try this last edit... i sayd that you are removing just the parent of node but there is another parent who contain the element, that's why when you exec this code `var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; ` it return the last number of children...

Comment: the result is still the same, when I add pasal 3 and 4, then I delete pasal 3 then I add a new pasal , then the number will give pasal 4

Comment: Aaaaa yeh i get it @AdityaDS wait and what number you want in this case ??

Comment: I want numbers and tabs to be obtained dynamically. so, when I delete the number 3 and add it again, the number that appears is 3 and when I add it again the number 5 appears and then sorted as before before being deleted.